# How to implement security with Google App Engine datastore namespaces?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, rest, namespaces

Inn my web-app I use datastore namespace to separate the data for the different users. How can I be sure that a user can't change a different users data?

In the documentation [pages](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/multitenancy/multitenancy#Python_Creating_namespaces_on_a_per_user_basis) it says that you have to implement you own security if the Keys are coming from untrusted sources. And since I have implemented a REST-API it exposes the GAE keys to the users. But it does not specify how the security should be implemented...

The namespace is the `users.get_current_user().user_id()`. How do i check that the object that is about to be changed is has the current users id as its namespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
user_ns = users.get_current_user().user_id()
entity_ns = my_entity.key.namespace()      # NDB datastore
# entity_ns = my_entity.key().namespace()  # DB datastore
if user_ns == entity_ns:
    # Save the entity if the namespaces are the same
    my_entity.put()
```

Comment: Perfekt, the fact that Key has a namespace() method was the missing piece of the puzzle:-)